# A tough question on meromorphic functions- Conway

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

This is a question I came across in JB Conways book.

> Let $f$ be meromorphic function in the punctured disk $D_r(z_0)$ \
>   {$z_0$}. Suppose there is a sequence {$p_n$} of poles of $f$ in
>   $D_r(z_0)$ \ {$z_0$} such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p_n=z_0$.
>   Show that for each $w\in \mathbb{C}$ there is a sequence {$z_n$} in
>   $D_r(z_0)$ \ {$z_0$} such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}z_n=z_0$ and
>   $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(z_n)=w$

I find this question very challenging and I am sorry for not showing any effort as I could not figure out anything. Hope someone can give me a hint so that I can work on it to get the answer. Thanks !

Comment: this seems like an extension of Casoriti Weierstrauss, for each pole you can find a sequence which limits to $w$. I suppose you just need to link those together somehow... unfortunately, I have not proved Casoriti Weirestrauss so that is as far as I can go here.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Isn't Casoriti Weierstrauss related to essential singularities?

Comment: I may be wrong but doesn't this follow immediately from the Casorati-Weierstaß theorem? With the poles accumulating at $z_0$, f must have an essential singularity there. C-S states that the image of an arbitrary small neighbourhood of $z_0$ under $f$ is dense in C.

Comment: How can you say that the accumulation point of the poles is an essential singularity?

Comment: @Heisenberg: If f has a pole at $z_0$ then the pole must be isolated. If f has a removable singularity at $z_0$ then f is holomorphic in a neighbourhood.

Comment: @MartinR I thought that since a pole is also an isolated singularity f is analytic in that neighborhood

Comment: @Heisenberg: Yes. What I meant is that both for a pole and for a removable singularity, there is a neighbourhood that does not contain poles. So it must be an essential singularity.

Comment: @MartinR So what you are saying is that there is no neighborhood around $z_0$ such that f is analytic so $z_0$ is an essential singularity? interesting

Comment: There are only 3 kinds of isolated singularities (for functions meromorphic in a punctured disk): removable, pole and essential. There is nothing else possible.

Comment: Note that $z_0$ is **not** an isolated singularity.

Comment: @Heisenberg: My comments are probably wrong. What I said is correct for a function *holomorphic* in a punctured disk. I am not sure anymore if it can be applied here directly.

Comment: @mrf true I realized it since i no punctured disk centered at $z_0$ is $f$ analytic.

Comment: @MartinR clearly $z_0$ is not a essential singularity. So maybe I can use that to get an answer we will see

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this follows directly from the Casorati-Weierstraß theorem, but
I think that it can be proved in a similar way.

The statement

> For each $w\in \mathbb{C}$ there is a sequence {$z_n$} in
>   $D_r(z_0)$ \ {$z_0$} such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}z_n=z_0$ and
>   $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(z_n)=w$

can be equivalently formulated as

> For each $w\in \mathbb{C}$ and for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a 
>   $z \in D_r(z_0) \setminus {z_0}$ with $\left| z-z_0 \right| < \varepsilon $
>   and $\left| f(z) - w_0 \right| < \varepsilon $.

Let us assume that this is **false**. Then we have

> There is a $w_0 \in \mathbb C$ and an $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ such 
>   that $\left| f(z) - w_0 \right| \ge \varepsilon_0 $ for all
>   $z \in D_r(z_0)  \setminus {z_0}$ with $\left | z-z_0 \right| < \varepsilon_0 $.

Then the function $g := 1/(f - w_0)$ is holomorphic and bounded in a punctured
disk with center $z_0$ and therefore has a removable singularity at $z_0$.

Therefore $f = w_0 + 1/g$ has a meromorphic extension to $U_{\varepsilon_0}(z_0)$. This contradicts
the assumption that the poles of $f$ accumulate at $z_0$.

Comment: I just don't get your statement $w_0 \in \mathbb C$ and an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\left| f(z) - w_0 \right| \ge \varepsilon $ for all $z$ with
$0 < \left | z-z_0 \right| < \varepsilon $.

Comment: @Heisenberg: Otherwise for all $w$ and for all $\varepsilon$ there would be a $z$ with $0 < |z-z_0| < \varepsilon$ and $|f(z) - f(w)| < \varepsilon$. Taking $\varepsilon = 1/n$ you get a sequence $(z_n)$ with $z_n \to z_0$ and $f(z_n) \to w$.

Comment: What if put it this way. there exists some $\epsilon >o$ such that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $z_n$ in the punctured disk and for each $\delta >0$, $0<|z_n - z_0|< \delta$ and $|f(z_n)-w|\geq \epsilon$

Comment: I edited my last comment hope you noticed

Comment: @Heisenberg: I have edited the answer, is it better understandable now?

Comment: Yep this is good just a have some trouble with the equivalent statements but anyway this looks correct

Comment: @Heisenberg: Which direction is unclear? What can I do to make it clear?

Comment: How the 1st statement is equivalent to the second. Not that I see anything wrong in it. I know it should be correct but just can't figure out how yet.

Comment: @Heisenberg: It is quite similar to the definition of continuity at a point where you have a "epsilon-delta" definition and a definition in terms of sequences. – Roughly: (1)->(2): For $\varepsilon > 0$ choose $z_n$ with $n$ large enough. (2)->(1): For every $n \in \mathbb N$ set $\varepsilon = 1/n$ to get a $z_n$.